# codeigniter mysql query equal date but can't display the result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have these active record `( [date(orderDate)] => 2016-10-21 [CURDATE()] => 2016-10-21 )`

but when I do this condition in codeigniter `$this->db->where('date(orderDate)', 'CURDATE()')`

It doesn't show the result.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$this->db->where('date(orderDate)', 'CURDATE()');
```

to

```
$this->db->where('date(orderDate)',date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Comment: @makii check this

Comment: thanks for your answer @dhruv i just modified a little since i just need to capture the date and not datetime. btw do you have any explanation why mysql curdate wont work this way?

Comment: CURDATE() is a mysql function not a codeigniter one.  If you wanted to use CURDATE() then you would have to manually build the statement `$this->db->query( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date( orderDate ) = CURDATE()' );`

Comment: Welcome @makii..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way,

```
$this->db->where('DATE(orderDate)','DATE(NOW())');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with date data you should be particular about selection may be you are storing data in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

and you are trying to select in YYYY-MM-DD format so hour minute and second will not match your selection try using following method

from

```
$this->db->where('date(orderDate)', 'CURDATE()');
```

to

```
$this->db->where('left(orderDate, 10)', 'CURDATE()');
```

or

```
$this->db->where('left(orderDate, 10)',date("Y-m-d"));
```